# Library for driving P10 LED Display with ESP32

Tags: microcontroller, led-driver, led-matrix

I am trying to make a 10 digit cricket scoreboard for which, I want to use P10 LED modules as digits.

My objective is to change the score from Mobile Phone via BLE.

ESP32 microcontroller suits best for my application as it has WiFi and BLE both.

However, the only problem is that I am unable to find any library for ESP32 (I prefer ESP-IDF based library, not Arduino based) which can be used to control the P10 displays.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Arduino libraries with ESP-IDF fairly easily by including [arduino-esp32 as a component](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/esp-idf_component.md) of ESP-IDF. After all, arduino-esp32 is based on ESP-IDF.

If you really, really don’t want to touch anything remotely to do with Arduino then I would suggest you peruse the code of one of the libraries for P10 (such as [this](https://github.com/pixelmatix/SmartMatrix/tree/teensylc)) and extract the Arduino independent parts.

Comment: I went with your second suggestion, and re-wrote some part of the existing P10 arduino library code for ESP32 FreeRTOS to display specific sets of digits and letters on P10 by sending them from ESP32 to P10 over SPI.